# Reason module system

Tags: ocaml, reason

https://facebook.github.io/reason/modules.html#modules-basic-modules

```
I don’t see any import or require in my file; how does module resolution work?

Reason/OCaml doesn’t require you to write any import; modules being referred to in the file are automatically searched in the project. Specifically, a module Hello asks the compiler to look for the file hello.re or hello.ml (and their corresponding interface file, hello.rei or hello.mli, if available).
A module name is the file name, capitalized. It has to be unique per project; this abstracts away the file system and allows you to move files around without changing code.
```

---

I tried reason modules system but can't understand how it works.

1) What the differents between `open` and `include`?

2) I have file `foo.re` with defined module `Foo`. I have file `bar.re` and want to call function from module `Foo`.

Should I `open` or `include` module `Foo` at `bar.re`?  Or just direct access - `Foo.someFunction`?

3) Module interfaces should be implemented only ay `*.rei` files? And module interface file should be with same name but with `rei` ext?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) `open` is like `import`, it adds the exported definitions in the opened module to the local namespace. `include` adds them to the module as if you copied the definitions from the included module to the includee. `ìnclude` will therefore also export the definitions (unless there's an interface file/signature that restricts what's exported of course)

2) you should prefer the most local use of a module that is convenient, in order to not unnecessarily pollute the namespace. So typically you'll want to use direct access, and only if a module has been specifically designed to be opened at file level should you do so. There are however forms of `open` that are more local than file level. You can `open` a module in just the scope of a function, or even scoped to a single expression in the form of `Foo.(someFunction 4 |> otherFunction 2)`

3) Toplevel (file) modules must be implemented in the form of an `rei` file with the same name as the `re` file. You can however define module types as "interfaces" for submodules.

OCaml's module system is quite extensive and flexible. I recommend reading the module chapter of Real World Ocaml to get a better grasp of it: https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/files-modules-and-programs.html